# Widget unfortunately has stopped android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem, Emulator shows alert dialog "Unfortunately, AppName has stopped" Thanks for help. I'd like to create clock widget.

**RmWidget.java**

> package lek.runningman.widget;
>
> ```
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
> import java.util.Date;
> import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
> import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.widget.RemoteViews;
>
> public class RmWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
>   // Define the format string for the date
>
>   private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
>       "hh:mm:ss\nEEEEEEEE\nd-MMM-yyyy");
>
>   @Override
>   public void onUpdate(Context context,AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
>
>   // Retrieve and format the current date
>   String now = formatter.format(new Date());
>
>   // Change the text in the widget
>   RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(
>   context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
>   updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, now);
>   appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, updateViews);
>
>   //super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
>   onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
>
>   }
> }
> ```

**widget.xml**

> ```
> android:minWidth="220dip"
> android:minHeight="146dip"
> android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"
> android:initialLayout="@layout/main">
> </appwidget-provider>
> ```

**main.xml**

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/text"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>     android:text="@string/app_name"
>     android:textStyle="bold"
>
>       android:typeface="monospace"
>     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>     android:textSize="18sp" />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

**RmWidget Manefest.xml**

> ```
>     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
>
>     <application
>         android:icon="@drawable/icon"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <receiver 
>             android:name=".RmWidget"
>             android:label="@string/widget_name" >
>
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
>           </intent-filter>
>
>             <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
>                      android:resource="@xml/widget" />
>
>         </receiver>
>     </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```

Comment: There must be an exception thrown somewhere. It's best to include a call stack (from the logs) in here so that we can help you diagnose it.

Answer (score 1):

Endless recursion for onUpdate, calling onUpdate on last line. Simply remove call.

Answer (score -1):

Create the following method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_filename);
 }
```

It is essential to initialize layout otherwise it will give some issues.

Comment: i can't call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); but my widget can ran in 3 seconds after that it has stopped.

Comment: last **LogCat**: `dalvikvm GC_CURRENT freed 462k, 8% free 6221k/7175k, puased 5ms+4ms`